# Angular Uso del *ngIf con dependiendo de un select

Tags: angular

Tengo este formulario que tiene un select y dependiendo y si se selecciona **si** se mostrara un textarea. Pero ahora misma lo muestra aun cuando se selecciona el **no**. Este es mi formulario html

```
<select
[(ngModel)]="condicion"
name="condicion"
required
placeholder="Selecciona"
required
>
<option value="true">Sí</option>
<option value="false">No</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="condicion">
<textarea
[(ngModel)]="descripcion"
name="descripcion"
placeholder="Escriba aquí"
></textarea>
</div>
```

Y esta es mi archivo typescript

```
export class Input implements OnInit {
      condicion: boolean;
      descripcion: string;
      constructor() {}
      ngOnInit() {}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres que la template trate los valores `true` y `false` como valores boleanos y no strings tienes que usar la sintaxis de template binding en `<option>`. Es decir, usar `[]` para que angular sepa que es una expresión javascript.

En tu caso, ambos valores evaluan a cierto porque `condicion` contiene strings como `"true"` `"false"` y no boleanos.

```
<select
[(ngModel)]="condicion"
name="condicion"
required
placeholder="Selecciona"
required
>
<option [value]="true">Sí</option>
<option [value]="false">No</option>
</select>
```